# how to configure accounts-ui in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using Accounts-ui-unstyled in my meteor app.I am trying to make my app go to the home page when clicking the logout in loginButtons.

```
 // Here is the code for welcome page for user

     <template name="MemberWelcome">
      <h1>My Profile</h1>
      {{> loginButtons}}
      </template>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you using for routing? Flow Router, Iron Router, etc?

Comment: @jordanwillis  
I am using Iron Router

Answer (score 0):

Set the homeRoute in accounts config:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  homeRoute: '/'
});
```

It should work.

Comment: Where should I enter this code?, In the client or server side??

Comment: I placed the code in a client side .js file and it doesn't work.There is no change of routes upon sign out

Comment: Wich router you are using? you can define before action route in iron router and check is user logged in or not and redirect user to home page if not logged in. and do not need do this.